# Linux: Substitute text fields with values from other file

Tags: linux, awk, scripting, text-processing

Alright, I cannot figure out how to do this.

I have a FileA which looks like this :

```
([7]RIMS_ID)                                            : "CNR"       
(refGain_A[7])                                          : 1           
(RIMSclockBias_A[7])                                    : -398015316.7
(RIMSclockDrift_A[7])                                   : -6442.29    
(RIMSclockSigma_A[7])                                   : .01         
(RIMSclockSigY_A[7])                                    : 0        

([8]RIMS_ID)                                            : "ABS"       
(refGain_A[8])                                          : 1           
(RIMSclockBias_A[8])                                    : -374515458
(RIMSclockDrift_A[8])                                   : -6442.29    
(RIMSclockSigma_A[8])                                   : .01         
(RIMSclockSigY_A[8])                                    : 0
```

and so on where the [index] goes from 0 to 71 and each station has a different ID.

I want to replace the value corresponding to RIMSclockBias_A string of each station with a value I have on another file B like this:

```
CNR -44163754.49
ABS 3417370.112
...
```

So to have:

```
([7]RIMS_ID)                                            : "CNR"       
(refGain_A[7])                                          : 1           
(RIMSclockBias_A[7])                                    : -44163754.49
(RIMSclockDrift_A[7])                                   : -6442.29    
(RIMSclockSigma_A[7])                                   : .01         
(RIMSclockSigY_A[7])                                    : 0        

([8]RIMS_ID)                                            : "ABS"       
(refGain_A[8])                                          : 1           
(RIMSclockBias_A[8])                                    : 3417370.112
(RIMSclockDrift_A[8])                                   : -6442.29    
(RIMSclockSigma_A[8])                                   : .01         
(RIMSclockSigY_A[8])                                    : 0
```

I can isolate the correct field in fileA with a combination of grep in a for loop and awk, but I don't know how I can replace the value in the file itself. 
Maybe I should use Perl but I don't have any experience.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly more readable, in my opinion:

```
BEGIN { FS = " *:? *" }
NR == FNR { bias["\"" $1 "\""] = $2; next }
/RIMS_ID/ { key = $2; }
/RIMSclockBias_A/ { sub($2, bias[key]); }
{ print }
```

Now, if you wanted to limit substitution to a certain range of IDs, say 57 to 64, you could use something like this:

```
BEGIN { FS = " *:? *" }
NR == FNR { bias["\"" $1 "\""] = $2; next }
/RIMS_ID/ { key = $2; }
/\[57\]RIMS_ID/ { substitute = 1 }
/\[65\]RIMS_ID/ { substitute = 0 }
/RIMSclockBias_A/ && substitute { sub($2, bias[key]); }
{ print }
```

So, as soon as ID 57 is encountered, we set `substitute` to true, and as soon as ID 65 is encountered, we set `substitute` to false, and we only carry out the substitution while that variable is true.

Comment: This version I can read better in fact. I've written it in a file script.awk and invoked then with: awk -f script.awk fileB fileA

Comment: Is there a way to apply the substitutions only for a certain range of indexes of fileA (let's say between 0 and 30)? Ignoring all the other that come afterwards?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can set and unset a variable when a certain pattern is encountered, and carry out the substitution only while the variable is set.

Comment: Ok, I've got it! Thank you @Michael Vehrs

Answer (score 1):

a not so robust `awk` script

```
$ awk -v q='"' 'NR==FNR{a[q $1 q]=$2;next} 
                $3 in a{v=a[$3]; f=1} 
   /\(RIMSclockBias_A\[[0-9]+\]\)/ && f {sub($3,v); f=0}1' map file

([7]RIMS_ID)                                            : "CNR"
(refGain_A[7])                                          : 1
(RIMSclockBias_A[7])                                    : -44163754.49
(RIMSclockDrift_A[7])                                   : -6442.29
(RIMSclockSigma_A[7])                                   : .01
(RIMSclockSigY_A[7])                                    : 0

([8]RIMS_ID)                                            : "ABS"
(refGain_A[8])                                          : 1
(RIMSclockBias_A[8])                                    : 3417370.112
(RIMSclockDrift_A[8])                                   : -6442.29
(RIMSclockSigma_A[8])                                   : .01
(RIMSclockSigY_A[8])                                    : 0
```

where file is the data file and map is the lookup values.  Assumes your structure is fixed (same number of fields, spacing and order of fields etc).

Comment: You should state in what ways it's not robust it is as it's not obvious and won't show up with the sample input. For example it'd convert `(RIMSclockBias_A[7]) : 7` to `(RIMSclockBias_A[-44163754.49]) : 7` and there's other non-obvious ways it could quietly do something unexpected given other input values.

Comment: there is no block level integrity.  If one block is missing the target field, and next is missing the match field.  The replacement will be wrong.  I think the same for your script too.  Perhaps, `RS=` can be set and iterate over the fields for each record, but I wanted to let the OP to come up with concerns.

Comment: IMHO it's safe to assume all the fields will be present since they always are in the posted sample input and let the OP tell us otherwise, but it's not OK to assume anything about the values of data that follow the same format (e.g. numbers) of the posted sample input without stating those assumptions.

Comment: that's given: "where the [index] goes from 0 to 71"

Comment: but what's not given is "the $3 value cannot be an integer from 0 to 71" which is what would be one of the requirements to make your script more robust. Look, all I'm saying is that when there's something non-obvious that would break a solution if it happened and has non-insignficant chance of occurring in the real data then we should state it, that's all.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Anyway you can assume all the blocks are present. Karafka solution seems working fine.

Comment: @Dad85 yes, that is the point of my comments above, it **will** seem to be working fine right up until you hit some perfectly valid, normal input values where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { map["\""$1"\""]=$2; next }
/^\(\[/ { key = $NF }
/^\(RIMSclockBias_A\[/ && key in map { sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*$/,map[key]) }
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk fileB fileA
([7]RIMS_ID)                                            : "CNR"
(refGain_A[7])                                          : 1
(RIMSclockBias_A[7])                                    : -44163754.49
(RIMSclockDrift_A[7])                                   : -6442.29
(RIMSclockSigma_A[7])                                   : .01
(RIMSclockSigY_A[7])                                    : 0

([8]RIMS_ID)                                            : "ABS"
(refGain_A[8])                                          : 1
(RIMSclockBias_A[8])                                    : 3417370.112
(RIMSclockDrift_A[8])                                   : -6442.29
(RIMSclockSigma_A[8])                                   : .01
(RIMSclockSigY_A[8])                                    : 0
```

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton, anyway it doesn't work. I run your code as it is and it simply makes nothing (no substitutions are made). Am I forgetting something?

Comment: If my solution doesn't work then your awk is not POSIX compliant. If you are using nawk or mawk, for example, those don't support POSIX character classes like `[[:space:]]` so you'd need to use hard-coded character lists like `[ \t]` instead. Try `sub(/[^ \t]+[ \t]*$/,map[key])` instead of `sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*$/,map[key])` and look into getting a POSIX awk (preferably GNU awk 4.1.*).